# How to link a temporary file with the users session in Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

Something like the following is written in the `Ruby on Rails` guides:

> Do not store large objects in a session. Instead you should store them in the database and save their id in the session. [..]
>   – http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-guidelines

I would like to connect temporary files (e. g. a text file and a 1.2M JPEG picture) with the user session in `Ruby on Rails 4.1`. The database is no option. I don't want to save files in a blob nor do I want to persist a record to get an `ID`, because it's a temporary file. I would like to have a clean system, so the temporary files should be cleaned up, after they expire. Similar to the session management of `PHP`.

Also the other session store types, which Rails offer, dosen't seem to be suitable for this.

Is there already a gem out there, which I can use? **Is there a `Rails` path I don't see, to do something like that? Is that behaviour for some reasons unusual for `Rails`?**

#### Tl;dr

I just recently realized the differences between how `PHP` stores session content and how `Ruby on Rails` does that. `PHP` only stores the session ID at the client side - the content is stored in files on the server, while `Rails` with it's `CookieStore` saves everything on the client side. The temporary files of `PHP` are cleaned up since `PHP 5.3` by the garbage collector and it's cron task.

Comment: just store the filename somewhere in the session. just don't forget to go remove that filename when the session is killed/expired, or you'll have a zillion orphaned temp files lying around. PHP would clean up the session file, but it wouldn't clean up any files you've attached to that session - that's not PHP's job.

Comment: what exactly are you storing?

Comment: @dax: temporary files - for example a 1.2M sized JPEG picture.

Answer (score 2):

Use memcache or something similar. Create a token and store that in the session, then use that to access the cache.

For a PNG image:

```
# controller
session[:tmp_token] = SecureRandom.hex(12)
Rails.cache.put(session[:tmp_token], binary_png_data_converted_to_base_64)
```

Display base64 encoded png

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <%= Rails.cache.fetch(session[:tmp_token]}%>" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I can use the session id as token, so I don't need to update my cookie?

Comment: You could use the session id, adding to the cookie another random hex value doesn't do any harm.

Comment: I more thinking about when I upload the file via AJAX, the session don't get updated.

Comment: Render a js.erb view as the response for the AJAX request, which will insert the image/html you want back into the HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should define another cache besides the cache which Rails already uses for caching. What would you suggest?

Comment: You can change the cache backend through environment configuration. So to use memcache find the line `config.cache_store` and add `:memcache, ['localhost:11211']`. This would require having the memcache gem installed.